# Is $f (x) = x^2$ a convex function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

Since the second derivative is $0$, how do we check if this is concave or convex?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The second derivative is $0$?

Comment: OH! My bad, it's 2!

Comment: FWIW a function with the second derivative $0$ is linear, thus convex. $x^2$ however has the second derivative equal to the constant $ 2 \gt 0$ and is therefore (non linear and) *strictly* convex.

Comment: It is the "queen" of all convex functions!

Answer (score 2):

$(x^2)''=2>0$.

Thus, it's a convex function.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a graph of $x^2$ and see that the chord joining any two points of the graph lies above the graph. so the function is convex